# Is there a better way to store data about 2 table relationship?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

Currently, I have one SQL Database with a tables.

I'll call them table A, and table B.
Each table A item is associated with anywhere from 0 to all existing table B columns (I use a sort of 'tags' system, which are stored in that B table)

Right now my solution to this was to create a third table, call it C, which simply has three columns -

```
Id(key) 
AId
BId
Count
```

---

**example**

So if I have A item with ID 1

```
Id| Name
1 | ColumnOne
```

Which is associated with 3 other items from table B - e.g, Id: 1, 2, 3

```
Id| Name
1 | TagOne
2 | TagTwo
3 | TagThree
```

Then C is going to look something like

```
Id|AId|BId
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 3
```

---

I just feel it's pretty redundant to have multiple entries for the same A table. **Is there some better way to do this?**

Comment: This is the *right* way to express an n-m relationship in SQL.  The other ways are generally inferior.  In fact, the table you want to create has a name -- an *association table* or *junction table*.

Comment: That is the way to do it. It might look less redundant if you needed audit like who created the link, when and keep a history of deleted link.

Comment: This is pretty much the only way to do it, if you're modeling a many-to-many (As can have many Bs and Bs can have many As). The only potential improvement is to make the foreign keys together a composite primary key for the table. This creates a unique-together constraint, so you don't end up in a situation where the same A is associated with the same B multiple times.

Comment: Thanks everyone. At least learned about Association tables and composite keys from this thread!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to determine the type of relationship between these 2 tables. If each record of table A is associated with multiple elements (0 or more) of table B, and each record of table B is also associated multiple elements of table A, then you have a **many-to-many** relationship. In this case, you have to create a third table (table C) with a composite primary key consisting of the primary keys of tables A and B. This means that you can drop the Id column:

Table C:

```
AId|BId
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
```